# CSS - inputs não estao alinhados

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<span class="input-label">New Password:</span>
<input id="password" type="password" name='password' placeholder="Insert new password">
<br> <span class="input-label">Confirm New Password:</span>
<input id="cpassword" type="password" placeholder="Confirm new password" name="confirmpassword" autocomplete="new-password">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit_password">
```

Pensei que ao usar `labels` fosse alinhar os `inputs`, mas não é isso que acontece, como mostra a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Diana!
Existem vários meios para se fazer isso, vou mostrar um.

A tag `span`, por padrão, vem com `display: inline;`, que não funcionará com a propriedade `width` que irei usar para uma das possíveis soluções para seu problema. Segue abaixo o código `CSS`, que define um valor fixo para o `width` e também altera seu `display` para `inline-block`, e por fim alinha o texto para direita.

```
.input-label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 180px;
}
```

Você pode ver o código funcionando [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/lucasfontesgaspareto/dd2yugn8/2/).
Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre display [aqui](http://pt-br.learnlayout.com/display.html) e [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display)

**Obs*** no HTML5 temos uma variedade de elementos semanticamente qualificados para cada tipo de estrutura de uma pagina.html, por exemplo, ao invés de usar `span` para definir o label, você pode usar a própria tag `<label></label>`.